# Sending commands serial port, MVC Application

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, applet, serial-port

I'm developing a MVC C# applications, and i need to send raw commands to the serial port, and i want to know what is the best way to do this, is there a way to do this with c#(i guess not because this code is running on server side, and the hardware is in the client side)? Or i need a Java Applet?

I've been checking [this](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) but it is for printing, would it work?
(i haven't tested it because the terminal that i want to send the commands is being delivered)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a web page read from the user's serial port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171522/how-can-a-web-page-read-from-the-users-serial-port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using an ASP.NET MVC web application and now want to access the client's (browser machine) serial port. This isn't possible with ASP.NET MVC without additional client software like a signed Java Applet or other software installed on the client machine (like a service, browser plugin or background application.)

This thread may be of use:

[How to read from Serial port in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310643/how-to-read-from-serial-port-in-a-webpage)

Comment: Thank you, but, in the answer of this thread, the example link seems to be broken :S

Comment: You're welcome. try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643264/dynamically-loading-a-native-library-inside-java-applet