# What are the colplications with using jni in a java applet?

Tags: java, applet, java-native-interface

This might be a silly question. I am in the process of writing a website. I have already weighed the benifits of using C/C++ in this java program, though every thing i am going to do using C can be implemented in java(Not easily). This code would be written as an applet to be run on the website. I would like to know if anyone could tell me if jni works across different os'es in an applet, and what complications could using jni in an applet pose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this is a bad idea.  (And this applies to using all forms of native code library in applets, not just JNI libraries.)

First complication is that this can only possibly work in a trusted applet.  And (frankly) if a user says "OK" to dialog that asks if your applet should be trusted / run, they are probably making a big mistake.  (Potentially nasty applets + potentially nasty native libraries == BIG RISK!)

Second complication is that you need to write, build, test, etcetera a different version of the native library for each and every combination of hardware AND OS platform you want your website to support.  If you don't, your website won't work for some of your users.

If you have a corporate user base with a mandated COE and established trust relationships (e.g. preinstalled corporate certificates) these problems are more manageable, but there is still an issue in both cases.

Related:

- [Dynamically loading a native library inside Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643264/dynamically-loading-a-native-library-inside-java-applet)